# SomersDelta: Error in as.table.default(x) : cannot coerce to a tabl in R

Tags: r, dplyr

data example

```
sommer=structure(list(tub = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L), fq = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("tub", "fq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-75L))
```

i want calculate   SomersDelta

```
library("DescTools")
SomersDelta(sommer, direction = c("row", "column"))
```

and i get the error

```
Error in as.table.default(x) : cannot coerce to a table
```

also i want get spine plot

```
library("coin")
spineplot(sommer)
```

but i get the error

```
Error in margin.table(tab, 1) : 'x' is not an array
```

are there two errors interconnection?
How to calculate SomersDelta  and get spine plot like this
[spine plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfZ7e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires a `matrix` as input.  According to `?SomersDelta`

> x - a numeric vector or a table. A matrix will be treated as table.

Here, the dataset is a `data.frame` class.  We can convert it to `matrix` (`as.matrix`) and it should work fine

```
SomersDelta(as.matrix(sommer), direction = c("row", "column"))
#[1] -0.06137931
```

Comment: ,thank you, can you help me to get desired spine plot?

Comment: @Kogan for the `spine` plot, do you need the `tug` vs `fq`

Comment: @Kogan Do you need `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);gather(sommer) %>%  mutate_all(factor) %>% spineplot(value~ key, data = .)`